How do I perform recursive search in Oracle
I am currently encountering challenges in comprehending the implementation of recursive search within Oracle SQL.
My encounter with a HackerRank question necessitates the application of this concept. Although I refrain from disclosing the specific HackerRank inquiry, I intend to leverage it as a reference to devise the logic independently. However, I seek assistance in dissecting the problem and understanding its intricacies.
Should anyone possess alternative methodologies to achieve the desired outcome, I am open to exploring diverse solutions. Your contributions and insights are highly valued, and I eagerly anticipate your responses.
Below is my sceanrio.
I have a table called : employee
It as 3 columns -> emp_id , emp_date , emp_task
Data is like below
EMP_ID | EMP_DATE   | EMP_TASK
A1     | 01-04-2024 | 345
A2     | 01-04-2024 | 546
A3     | 01-04-2024 | 232
A4     | 01-04-2024 | 8000
A5     | 01-04-2024 | 2344
A1     | 02-04-2024 | 456
A2     | 02-04-2024 | 9280
A3     | 02-04-2024 | 324
A2     | 02-04-2024 | 754
A8     | 02-04-2024 | 75 
A2     | 03-04-2024 | 400
A3     | 03-04-2024 | 234
A3     | 04-04-2024 | 100

And the condition is to calculate the total number of emp_id participated.
It is clearly mentioned that : get count of those emp_id who participated in each day.
Make sure they were their from initil earlier date.
Here is the logic I need to implement recursively but not known how to start writing query ?.
If you see Day 1 : 01-04-2024   -> emp_id participated -> A1 , A2 , A3 , A4 , A5
If you see Day 2 : 02-04-2024    -> emp_id participated -> A1 , A2 , A3`. They are the one who participated in Day 1 as well so no of emp_id participated is 3
Similarly it continues till end.
Note : First day who participated need to be consider till end. They are participating.
A8 as joined in middle as this emp_id is not part of first day so in count it is not considered.
So my expected output is below need to be achieved
emp_date   cout_participated 
01-04-2024 5  
02-04-2024 3
03-04-2024 2
04-04-2024 1

My trials not implemented fully
WITH get_initial_day_emp_participated AS ( 
   -- Fetching all emp_id who initially participated
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        employee
    WHERE
        emp_date = (
            SELECT
                MIN(emp_date)
            FROM
                employee
        )
), get_count_initial_day_participated AS ( 
  -- Using group getting the count of emp_id who initially participated 
    SELECT
        emp_date,
        COUNT(DISTINCT emp_id)
    FROM
        get_initial_day_emp_participated
    GROUP BY
        emp_date
), get_details_except_first_date AS (
   -- Fetching all details except first day participated
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        employee
    WHERE
        emp_date != (
            SELECT
                MIN(emp_date)
            FROM
                employee
        )
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    get_details_except_first_date;

For you reference giving create table and insert details
create table employee
(
   EMP_ID     varchar2(10),
   EMP_DATE   date,
   EMP_TASK   number
);

Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A1',to_date('01-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),345);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A2',to_date('01-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),546);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A3',to_date('01-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),232);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A4',to_date('01-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),8000);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A5',to_date('01-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),2344);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A1',to_date('02-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),456);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A2',to_date('02-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),9280);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A3',to_date('02-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),324);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A2',to_date('02-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),754);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A8',to_date('02-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),75);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A2',to_date('03-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),400);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A3',to_date('03-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),234);
Insert into employee (EMP_ID,EMP_DATE,EMP_TASK) values ('A3',to_date('04-04-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),100);


Also show us your current query attempt.

@jarlh  : Ok sure but not reach up to that will show my query stuck

@jarlh : I have added my query tried so far

Why is a8 excluded from the second of April

@nbk : Need to consider only emp_id who intiallly first day participated and continued till end for each day. Its like common

This isn't recursive, but an alternative method is to count the number of days that have elapsed, and the number of days that an emp_id has been active:
select emp_id, emp_date,
  emp_date - min(emp_date) over() + 1 as day_num,
  count(*) over (partition by emp_id order by emp_date) emp_day_num
from (
  select distinct emp_id, emp_date
  from employee
)
order by emp_date, emp_id




EMP_ID
EMP_DATE
DAY_NUM
EMP_DAY_NUM




A1
01-APR-24
1
1


A2
01-APR-24
1
1


A3
01-APR-24
1
1


A4
01-APR-24
1
1


A5
01-APR-24
1
1


A1
02-APR-24
2
2


A2
02-APR-24
2
2


A3
02-APR-24
2
2


A8
02-APR-24
2
1


A2
03-APR-24
3
3


A3
03-APR-24
3
3


A3
04-APR-24
4
4



The subquery is because count(distinct emp_id) over ... isn't allowed.
The min(emp_date) over() is the analytic version on min(), and gives the earliest date across the whole data set, but available as a value to every row. Then emp_date - min(emp_date) over() gives the offset of each row's date from that minimum; adding 1 just makes it 1-4 instead of 0-3 to make it easier to compare.
count(*) over (partition by emp_id order by emp_date) is an analytic count that shows how many dates (distinct, because of the subquery) each emp_id has appeared so far, up to the current row's date. If an ID starts late or skips a date that count will no longer align with the day number.
Then see if they match, and count those that do:
select emp_date, count(emp_id)
from (
  select emp_id, emp_date,
    emp_date - min(emp_date) over() + 1 as day_num,
    count(*) over (partition by emp_id order by emp_date) emp_day_num
  from (
    select distinct emp_id, emp_date
    from employee
  )
)
where emp_day_num = day_num
group by emp_date
order by emp_date




EMP_DATE
COUNT(EMP_ID)




01-APR-24
5


02-APR-24
3


03-APR-24
2


04-APR-24
1



fiddle

If you want a recursive approach then you could use a recursive CTE:
with rcte (emp_id, emp_date) as (
  select emp_id, emp_date
  from employee
  where emp_date = (
    select min(emp_date) from employee
  )
  union all
  select r.emp_id, e.emp_date
  from rcte r
  join employee e
  on e.emp_id = r.emp_id
  and e.emp_date = r.emp_date + 1
)
select emp_date, count(distinct emp_id)
from rcte
group by emp_date
order by emp_date




EMP_DATE
COUNT(DISTINCTEMP_ID)




01-APR-24
5


02-APR-24
3


03-APR-24
2


04-APR-24
1



fiddle
The anchor branch is similar to your first CTE, the recursive branch looks for a matching ID the next day. For each row in the previous rcte result, it looks in employee for a row with same ID and the next day (which is r.emp_date + 1). Once there is a gap for an ID it stop appearing.

Thank you let me underatand the logic you tried. Can  you explain second query in details not aware about anchor and recursive

Why we are mentioning this : (emp_id, emp_date)  during cte . Already It is returning value from inside value  select emp_id, emp_date   from employee   where emp_date = (     select min(emp_date) from employee   )

I prefer it for CTEs anyway (over having to remember to add aliases to the inner query), but it is required for a recursive CTE - it will error if you don’t have that column list.

The first query is still unpredictable what is happening in logic trying to break down to understand.  If you could add some more explanation I will get some idea. Not able to pick logic what is happening

Can you explain why this is needed : r.emp_date + 1

@stackoverflowquestion54develo - I've added a bit more explanation, hopefully that helps.

From Oracle 12, you can:

Find the earliest date in the table use the MIN analytic function
Use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to perform row-by-row pattern matching to find the employees who were there on the first day and any consecutive days.
Then COUNT the matched rows for each day.

SELECT emp_date,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                emp_id,
                emp_date,
                MIN(emp_date) OVER () AS first_day
         FROM   employee 
       )
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY emp_id
         ORDER BY     emp_date
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( ^ first_row consecutive* )
         DEFINE
           first_row   AS emp_date = first_day,
           consecutive AS PREV(emp_date) + 1 = emp_date
       )
GROUP BY
       emp_date

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



EMP_DATE
COUNT(*)




2024-04-01 00:00:00
5


2024-04-02 00:00:00
3


2024-04-03 00:00:00
2


2024-04-04 00:00:00
1



fiddle

Nice solution how it works but could not able to understand.

Took reference from @Alex Poole and try to break down the logic
Step 1 : Getting day wise details
  select 
  emp_id ,
  emp_date,
  dense_rank() over(order by emp_date)  as day_participated
  from employee


Step 2 : Getting each day when an emp_id included
   select 
   emp_id,
   emp_date,
   dense_rank() over(partition by emp_id order by emp_date ) as each_day_of_emp_id
   from employee


Step 3 : Joining both tables as inner join based on emp_id and emp_date and  day_participated = each_day_participated
SELECT
    *
FROM
         get_each_day_participated a
    JOIN get_no_of_days_each_emp_id_participated b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
                                                      AND a.emp_date = b.emp_date
                                                      AND a.day_participated = b.each_day_of_emp_id
ORDER BY
    a.emp_date ASC,
    a.emp_id ASC

Note : A8 is excluded because the following condition does not match a.day_participated = b.each_day_of_emp_id

Over all CTE query
WITH get_each_day_participated AS (
  -- Getting day wise details 
    SELECT
        emp_id,
        emp_date,
        DENSE_RANK()
        OVER(
            ORDER BY
                emp_date
        ) AS day_participated
    FROM
        employee
), get_no_of_days_each_emp_id_participated AS (
   -- Getting each day when an emp_id included 
    SELECT
        emp_id,
        emp_date,
        DENSE_RANK()
        OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id
             ORDER BY
                 emp_date
        ) AS each_day_of_emp_id
    FROM
        employee
)
SELECT
        a.emp_id as id ,a.emp_date as dt
FROM
         get_each_day_participated a
    JOIN get_no_of_days_each_emp_id_participated b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
                                                      AND a.emp_date = b.emp_date
                                                      AND a.day_participated = b.each_day_of_emp_id
ORDER BY
    a.emp_date ASC,
    a.emp_id ASC

Now applying group by on CTE query and calculating count(distinct emp_id)
SELECT
    dt                 AS each_day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS participated
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.emp_id   AS id,
            a.emp_date AS dt
        FROM
                 get_each_day_participated a
            JOIN get_no_of_days_each_emp_id_participated b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
                                                              AND a.emp_date = b.emp_date
                                                              AND a.day_participated = b.each_day_of_emp_id
        ORDER BY
            a.emp_date ASC,
            a.emp_id ASC
    )
GROUP BY
    dt
ORDER BY
    dt;

Final query :
WITH get_each_day_participated AS (
  -- Getting day wise details 
    SELECT
        emp_id,
        emp_date,
        DENSE_RANK()
        OVER(
            ORDER BY
                emp_date
        ) AS day_participated
    FROM
        employee
), get_no_of_days_each_emp_id_participated AS (
   -- Getting each day when an emp_id included 
    SELECT
        emp_id,
        emp_date,
        DENSE_RANK()
        OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id
             ORDER BY
                 emp_date
        ) AS each_day_of_emp_id
    FROM
        employee
)
SELECT
    dt                 AS each_day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS participated
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.emp_id   AS id,
            a.emp_date AS dt
        FROM
                 get_each_day_participated a
            JOIN get_no_of_days_each_emp_id_participated b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
                                                              AND a.emp_date = b.emp_date
                                                              AND a.day_participated = b.each_day_of_emp_id
        ORDER BY
            a.emp_date ASC,
            a.emp_id ASC
    )
GROUP BY
    dt
ORDER BY
    dt;

Output :

Incase if you find any issue in solution feel free to edit it and help me to learn.
I learned from stackoverflow and writing logics
